# Present Perfect or Present Perfect Continuous

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

If the Present Perfect is used to focus on the completed action and on the result, why do we say:

> "I have been cycling (Present Perfect Continuous) all day and my legs are really tired now."

The action of cycling has completely finished.

Comment: Not necessarily. You might say it while you were still cycling.

Comment: The *present perfect* is not the same as *present perfect continuous*.

Answer (score 1):

This use of the present perfect continuous focuses on an action that has recently stopped but its effects are still apparent. The action = cycling all day (duration) has recently stopped but the effects = tired legs are still continuing.

Answer (score 0):

You have been cycling **all day**

Situation 1: You have just finished cycling.(but the action continued until now)

Situation 2: You are still cycling.

Visualize yourself cycling and telling someone that you have been cycling all day.